# Twitter Timeline not showing up in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, twitter, timeline

I've embedded a twitter timeline on a website but it's not showing on Chrome (Version 66). Developer Tools shows a javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __twttr.callbacks.tl_i0_profile_anonymized_old is not a function at cdn.syndication.twimg.com/timeline/profile?callback=__twttr.callbacks.tl_i0_profile_anonymized_old&dnt=false&domain=www.trier-football.de&lang=de&screen_name=anonymized&suppress_response_codes=true&t=1696882&tz=GMT%2B0200&with_replies=false:1
```

It works on Firefox, Opera, Edge and even IE ;)

Is this a known problem? I didn't found anything on google. Does someone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you replicate this in an incognito session?

Comment: Added code highlighting

Comment: Hmm, it seems the problem has solved itself.... yesterday I had the mentioned error message but now it is gone for some reason :/